# Adding a navigation bar button

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to add a button to the navigation bar in the view, but it is not showing up.

I have:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"audio-controls"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(toggleAudioPlaybackView:)];
```

in a `viewDidLoad`.

EDIT: It is also important to note that I am also using storyboard.

EDIT: I think there is an issue with self.navigationItem... it's not nil but no changes are being made to it.

Comment: Does the image exist in your app bundle with that exact name (plus the .png extension)? Is the view controller being displayed in a `UINavigationController`?

Comment: Always check the pieces. Is `[UIImage imageNamed:@"audio-controls"]` nil?

Comment: @rmaddy Image name need not have ".png" extension.

Comment: @SRIKANTHKV It does if you don't specify an extension when calling `imageNamed:`.

Comment: @rmaddy It works for me even without giving the extension. Just tested  now to be sure.

Comment: @Julia, please check whether image with name "audio-controls" exists in your project and added to the targets. Check whether the image is copied to bundle(Project Settings->Build Phases->Copy Bundle Resources). Also check whether `self.navigationItem` is not nil. Make sure your ViewController's parent is NavigationController

Comment: @SRIKANTHKV Let's make sure we are saying the same thing. If the image has a png extension, then you don't need to specify the extension when calling `imageNamed:`. If the image has any other extension, then you must specify  the extension when calling `imageNamed:`. Since the OP didn't specify an extension when calling `imageNamed:`, the image must have an extension of png.

Comment: [UIImage imageNamed:@"audio-controls"] is not nil and audio-controls does exist in my project

Comment: @Julia You still haven't indicated whether this view controller is being shown inside a navigation controller or not.

Comment: This view controller is not inside a navigation controller. It is inside a UIView controller.

Comment: Then that is the problem. In order for the view controller's `navigationItem` to be displayed, the view controller must be displayed in a navigation controller.

Comment: But it works in some views that use the UIView controller